# How to investigate why a block device, though visible in lsusb, is not in lsblk?

Tags: usb, udev, block-device

I have several devices (which are essentially block type devices) that are connected via USB. Its USB mass storage devices. I can list the devices via
`lsusb` but they do not show up in `lsblk` or somewhere in `/sys/block`.

When doing a `udevadm monitor` and plug them in and out again I get this message

```
KERNEL[69676.974198] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[69676.974402] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1 (usb)
UDEV  [69676.975535] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [69676.976173] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1 (usb)
KERNEL[69679.190131] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1 (usb)
KERNEL[69679.195371] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [69679.197376] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1 (usb)
UDEV  [69679.199103] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.0 (usb)
```

This happens with this kernel `uname -a`

```
Linux ajvm 4.6.4-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Jul 11 19:12:32 CEST 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`dmesg` does not show something that explains the error either

```
[69680.813203] usb 2-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 10 using ehci-pci
[69683.770954] usb 2-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 10
```

What can I do to investigate this misbehaviour further?

What could be the reason that suddenly no new block devices are created?

**addition**
I indeed missed the `lsusb` output which is

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0bda:0159 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5159 Card Reader Controller
```

Further I should add that it **was** not only this one device, which did not trigger any block device node to be created, but it was all (several usb flash drives and sd cards inserted). I Hence looked for `usb-storage.ko` being loaded `lsmod | grep usb` which did not show the usb-storage module to be loaded.

**update**

It turned out that the reason for all of this, was that I updated my kernel, and *stupidly* already removed the old kernel package. Not having done a reboot, I was with the old kernel, yet not anymore its kernel modules, making the load of `usb-storage` impossible. What would have been obvious had I seen some error in the `dmesg` to complain about misssing kernel modules, which it didn't. 
So this problem being past, and the issue being apparent, I would yet find it interesting if there was an answer giving information about `what could have been done, for the detection of the problem?`. The usual suspect, i.e. a look into `dmesg` at least was not the way, how should I have been informed about the missing module (which was the cause of the problem)?

Comment: This is not a USB block device. All we can tell from the information you gave us is that it's a USB device and that the USB controller is an EHCI (USB2) controller connected to a PCI bus. What kind of device is it? You need to give us some information. At least the output of `lsusb`.